# How can I use Spark StreamingQueryProgress to accurately monitor performance?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, streaming, monitoring, spark-structured-streaming

I am using a StreamingQueryListener to output [StreamingQueryProgress](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQueryProgress.html) metrics to Kafka, in order to monitor my Spark structured streaming job's performance. These metrics include:

- numInputRecords: The number of records processed in a trigger
- inputRowsPerSecond: The rate of data arriving
- processedRowsPerSecond: The rate at which Spark is processing data
- triggerExecution: Approximate time in milliseconds to process this micro-batch

According to the Databricks blog [Taking Apache Spark's Structured Streaming to Production](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/18/taking-apache-sparks-structured-structured-streaming-to-production.html), you can monitor performance by comparing inputRowsPerSecond with processedRowsPerSecond: if the latter is consistently smaller than the former then your deployment needs to be scaled in order to keep up with incoming data.

Here are streaming query progress metrics for a tumbling window structured streaming computation using a single executor. I computed the average of processedRowsPerSecond and inputRowsPerSecond and confirmed that the compute resources are sufficient to keep up with the query.

```
timestamp     num input rows   proc r/s   input r/s    execution ms
04:38:40.577               8        1.0         1.1            7725
04:38:48.312            6408      829.6       828.4            7724
04:38:56.047               8        1.0         1.0            7955
04:39:04.011              10        1.1         1.3            9088
04:39:13.110            6408      797.7       704.3            8033
04:39:21.154               8        1.0         1.0            8111
04:39:29.275            3760      480.6       463.0            7824
04:39:37.108            2656      332.7       339.1            7983
04:39:45.102               0        0.0         0.0               3
04:39:45.491               8        1.1       615.4            7601
04:39:53.102            6400      815.0       840.9            7853
04:40:00.965               8        0.9         1.0            8883
04:40:09.858              13        1.6         1.5            7969
04:40:17.836            6408      810.2       803.2            7909
04:40:25.755               8        1.1         1.0            7456
04:40:33.220            6400      808.6       857.3            7915
04:40:41.145               8        1.1         1.0            7482
04:40:48.636              13        1.7         1.7            7523
04:40:56.168               8        1.1         1.1            7561
04:41:03.739               0        0.0         0.0               3
Progress summary   total_input_rows=38540.0
                   avg_processed_rates=744.7164839858403 
                   avg_input_rates=739.0657377541836 
                   total_execution_ms=142595.0
```

However I think in some cases this technique does not work. Below are results for a simple non-windowed query, reading from the input topic and writing to the output topic after a 0.5 millisecond computation. The progress data is shown below. In this case the average inputRowsPerSecond is 5 times higher than the average processedRowsPerSecond (even after weighting intervals by numInputRecords) -- yet the query was easily able to process all data records in the input stream during the test time interval.

```
timestamp     num input rows   proc r/s   input r/s    execution ms
01:58:41.456             326     1258.7     25076.9             259     
01:58:41.723            1745     1457.8      6535.6            1197     
01:58:42.929            4329     1235.8      3589.6            3503     
01:58:46.440               8       21.7         2.3             369     
01:58:46.817               0        0.0         0.0               3     
01:58:55.493               8      114.3       500.0              70     
01:58:55.572               0        0.0         0.0               3     
01:59:02.384              43      447.9      3307.7              96     
01:59:02.488             859     1403.6      8259.6             612     
01:59:03.108            4873     1153.6      7859.7            4224     
01:59:07.340             633      555.3       149.6            1140     
01:59:08.489               0        0.0         0.0             230     
01:59:15.490               8      121.2       666.7              66     
01:59:15.564               0        0.0         0.0               2     
01:59:23.217             136      925.2      9066.7             147     
01:59:23.372            1138     1493.4      7341.9             762     
01:59:24.143            5126      840.3      6648.5            6099     
01:59:30.250               8      135.6         1.3              59     
01:59:30.318               0        0.0         0.0               2     
01:59:35.485               4       67.8       333.3              59     
01:59:35.552               4       65.6        59.7              61     
01:59:35.622               0        0.0         0.0               2     
01:59:44.151              59      641.3      4916.7              92     
01:59:44.250             732     1402.3      7393.9             522     
01:59:44.780            4126     1605.4      7784.9            2570     
01:59:47.358            1491     1488.0       578.4            1002     
01:59:48.368               0        0.0         0.0               3     
01:59:55.489               8      131.1       666.7              61     
01:59:55.559               0        0.0         0.0               3     
02:00:05.008              77      445.1      5500.0             173     
02:00:05.190             994     1320.1      5461.5             753     
02:00:05.952            4533     1424.6      5948.8            3182     
02:00:09.142             804     1391.0       252.0             578     
02:00:09.728               0        0.0         0.0               2     
02:00:15.495               8       95.2       615.4              84     
02:00:15.588               0        0.0         0.0               3     
02:00:25.494               8       89.9       615.4              89     
02:00:25.592               0        0.0         0.0               4     
02:00:26.136               6       71.4       375.0              84     
02:00:26.228             718     1456.4      7804.3             493     
02:00:26.729            3843     1173.4      7670.7            3275     
02:00:30.013            1833     1229.4       558.2            1491     
02:00:31.512               0        0.0         0.0               3     
02:00:35.485               4       54.8       307.7              73     
02:00:35.567               4       60.6        48.8              66     
02:00:35.642               0        0.0         0.0               2     
02:00:45.494               8      101.3       666.7              79     
02:00:45.581               0        0.0         0.0               2     
02:00:55.494               8      112.7       615.4              71     
02:00:55.573               0        0.0         0.0               3     
Progress summary   total_input_rows=38512.0 
                   avg_processed_rates=1253.6837882613463 
                   avg_input_rates=6031.12344277613 
                   total_execution_ms=33461.0
```

Based on this progress data I confirmed that:

```
processedRowsPerSecond = numInputRecords / triggerExecution * 1000 msec/sec
inputRowsPerSecond = numInputRecords / (current timestamp - previous timestamp) * 1000 msec/sec
```

These two rates will only be comparable when triggerExecution time matches the time between progress record timestamps, and when these intervals are uniform in length. This is not generally the case with non-windowed queries.

Is there a recommended way to monitor non-windowed queries?

Comment: Hi, May I know what does the field triggerExecution specify? I ran a job and I saw that it is different for each batch.

Answer (score 0):

This complication (affecting non-windowed Spark structured streaming jobs) seems to go away if you identify the column representing your event time, EG:

```
val inputData = dataSource.toDecodedDs(spark)
  .withWatermark("time", "60 seconds")
```